# Given a polygon and a point in 2D, how can one find the feature (vertex or edge) of the polygon closest to the point?

Tags: geometry, game-physics

A naive approach is to find, for each edge in the polygon, the point on that edge closest to the given point, and then take the one that's closest. Is there a faster algorithm? My goal is to implement a 2D Super Mario Galaxy-style platformer.

Apparently this can be done with Voronoi regions, as in this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ldh2YKobuWo

However, I can't find any Voronoi algorithms that deal with edges as well as points. Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the polygon is convex, then the overhead of the voronoi calculation far exceeds that of the naive approach.

If this is run many times, and each time the point changes slightly, you only need to check 3 segments (think about it: as you move around, assuming many checks, then the closest edge will only change to an adjacent edge)

Comment: Last part is not true. Might change to a segment on the opposite side of the polygon if you start close to the middle, for example.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett If you are on the inside of the polygon, that is true.

Comment: Fortunately for my application, the point in question will never be inside the polygon. Hooray.

Comment: @Jake when the point is outside (which is what i assumed, given the nature of the question) my answer is correct

Comment: I agree! I don't know how you guessed that the point was outside... I guess I haven't played Super Mario in a long time.

Answer (score 2):

Calculate the [point-line distance](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Point-LineDistance2-Dimensional.html) for each of the edges, then pick the shortest one. There is no shortcut. [This site](http://paulbourke.net/geometry/pointlineplane/) has a good explanation and even implementations in various languages.

However, finding "the point on that edge closest to the given point" is a computationally unnecessary intermediate result.